# Is this an acceptable way to integrate?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I am supposed to find: $$ \int \sec(1-x)\tan(1-x) dx $$

I then set $ u = \sec(1-x) $
$$ du = -\tan(1-x)\sec(1-x)\ dx $$ therefore

$$ \frac{-du}{\sec(1-x)} = \tan(1-x)\ dx$$ 
Which when applied gives me this:
$$\int \sec(1-x) \frac{-du}{\sec(1-x)} = -\int 1\  du \\ = -\sec(1-x) + C $$

which is correct, but i feel like this is like cheating for some reason, is this not acceptable?

Comment: Why not? Integration by substitution is very acceptable.

Comment: It's ok, maybe you feel that way because you're plugging in $du/sec(1-x)$ instead of $du/u$, which would yield the same result.

Comment: yes i know but it just felt weird in this situation for some reason, like how you can set the integrand to equal one and then integrate. just like Rienmann's series theorem in a way.

Comment: Completely unacceptable. The mathematical community will be pressing charges immediately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've done just fine.

Alternately,

since $\dfrac{d}{dx}\left(\sec \theta\right) = \sec \theta \tan \theta$, it makes sense that $\int \sec\theta \tan\theta\,d\theta = \sec\theta + C$.

Now can you more readily recognize that your integrand is equal $\;-\dfrac{d}{dx}\big(\sec(1-x)\big),\:$ and what that means for $\;\int \sec(1-x)\tan(1-x)\,dx\;?$